# Creating a shortcut with command line arguments

Tags: c++, windows, command-line-arguments, shortcut

Using the code available on the link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969393.aspx

```
HRESULT CreateLink(LPCWSTR lpszPathObj1, LPCSTR lpszPathLink, LPCWSTR lpszDesc) 
{ 
    HRESULT hres; 
    IShellLink* psl; 

    // Get a pointer to the IShellLink interface. It is assumed that CoInitialize
    // has already been called.
    hres = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ShellLink, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IShellLink, (LPVOID*)&psl); 
    if (SUCCEEDED(hres)) 
    { 
        IPersistFile* ppf; 

        // Set the path to the shortcut target and add the description. 
        psl->SetPath(lpszPathObj1); 
        psl->SetDescription(lpszDesc); 

        // Query IShellLink for the IPersistFile interface, used for saving the 
        // shortcut in persistent storage. 
        hres = psl->QueryInterface(IID_IPersistFile, (LPVOID*)&ppf); 

        if (SUCCEEDED(hres)) 
        { 
            WCHAR wsz[MAX_PATH]; 

            // Ensure that the string is Unicode. 
            MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, lpszPathLink, -1, wsz, MAX_PATH); 

            // Add code here to check return value from MultiByteWideChar 
            // for success.

            // Save the link by calling IPersistFile::Save. 
            hres = ppf->Save(wsz, TRUE); 
            ppf->Release(); 
        } 
        psl->Release(); 
    } 
    return hres; 
}
```

I am trying to create a shortcut on the desktop, with a target (exe) that takes command line arguments.
I have tried to set the target in the following ways:

```
LPCWSTR lpszPathObj1 = L"C:/Folder1/Folder2/SomeApp.exe 690080776072629&734078";
```

Creates shortcut with Target:

```
"C:/Folder1/Folder2/SomeApp.exe 690080666072629&782078"
```

And

```
LPCWSTR lpszPathObj1 = L"C:/Folder1/Folder2/SomeApp.exe\" 690080776072629&734078";
```

Creates shortcut with blank target.

I have tried more options, but not working. Could someone help?

Comment: What have you tried? I don't think assigning to a `LPCWSTR` is going to create a shortcut (i.e. show the code you used)

Comment: The code I have used is from the link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969393.aspx

Comment: @eeerahul - there are multiple samples on that page, none of which have a variable named `lpszPathObj1`. Please show the code that *you* used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming the string you mentioned was passed to psl->setPath(). It is just to pass the executable that will be invoked by the link, you shouldn't put the arguments in the same string. Instead, call psl->setArguments() after that, just with the arguments.
The double quotes inside the string make no difference, they'd be needed only if you had one of the arguments with spaces inside it.